# Azure function firing twice- VS 2017 preview

Tags: c#, azure, azure-functions

I am having an issue with Azure function(Blog trigger.. etc), which fires multiple times for an event. This issue started once after i started using VS 2017 azure template to develop azure function.
Please note this happens even though i am not debugging in VS 2017

**Log:**

```
2017-06-23T06:46:52.055 Executing 'Functions.dafBlobTrigger' (Reason='New blob detected: input/NETSNEFS20161030052344898 - Copy30.XML', Id=XXXXXXXXX-f246-4f12-8454-XXXXXX56b1b1)
2017-06-23T06:46:52.055 Function started (Id=XXXXXXXXX-f246-4f12-8454-XXXXXX56b1b1) 
2017-06-23T06:46:52.055 C# Blob trigger function Processed blob  Name:20161030052344898 - Copy30.XML   Size: 61026 Bytes 
2017-06-23T06:46:52.220 Function completed (Success, Id=XXXXXXXXX-f246-4f12-8454-XXXXXX56b1b1, Duration=162ms) 
2017-06-23T06:46:52.220 Executed 'Functions.dafBlobTrigger' (Succeeded,     Id=XXXXXXXXX-f246-4f12-8454-XXXXXX56b1b1) 
2017-06-23T06:46:52.055 Function started (Id=XXXXXXXXX-f246-4f12-8454-XXXXXX56b1b1)
2017-06-23T06:46:52.055 C# Blob trigger function Processed blob Name:20161030052344898 - Copy30.XML   Size: 61026 Bytes
2017-06-23T06:46:52.220 Function completed (Success, Id=XXXXXXXXX-f246-4f12-8454-XXXXXX56b1b1, Duration=162ms)
```

Has anyone come across similar issue?

Thanks in advance
Ravi

Comment: These look like duplicate logs of a single execution. Can you share your 'host.json' file? Do you see this only locally? Or when deployed as well?

Comment: Don't have anything in host.json , i am having just like this  {}. Log what i have sent is from server, so this happens in deployed version.

Comment: Where do you see this log? In the file system, or in the Portal Logs section?

Comment: Also, check the logs in the Monitor tab. There shouldn't be duplicates there.

Answer (score 2):

This is probably caused by duplicate logs, which can happen in the portal Logs tab. You should instead look at executions in the Monitor tab or enable Application Insights.